# CICD with jenkins and sonarqube

Tags: jenkins, version-control, sonarqube

from the last week i am working with jenkins, and its going good but at the end of R&D I have lost of confusion, these are questions which confusingto me.

1. How to do Continuous Integration with jenkins of Website?
2. hoe to view Testing analysis reports produced by sonarqube server to my local system?
3. what happens where all my developers will do commit and push at the same time on repository?
4. How to deploy my web application on targeted server using jenkins?
5. How to I use sonarqube to test my website ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are building a .net website, install msbuild plugin in jenkins. Create a jenkins job, add a step checkout your website (git/svn - install required repo plugin). Schedule to run nightly or hourly depending on your needs.
2. Type in url for your sonarqube server and then you can view the reports.
3. This is not an issue if your developers are comitting simultaneously. Usually a CI tool such as Jenkins will take care of that.
4. This is called continuous deployment or continuous delivery. Something like Octopus Deploy can help you if you are deploying .net applications. You can use the tool octo.exe and pass the API key as parameter to deploy to a specific environment.
5. SonarQube is used as a quality gate for code analysis. It is not a test framework. Try to investigate on how to use selenium framework for automation testing.

I hope that I have answered your questions.